# host:port for testnet and mainnet

Tags: testnets, ethereum-wallet-dapp

I am testing my Dapp and need host:port for testnet and mainnet.
Please can you let me know where can I find these urls?
Also, what if the url (host:port) i provide and it goes down?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you create an account at https://infura.io. They're providing the infrastructure for what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to run your own node with `geth` and `geth --testnet`. This way you can connect to them from your app. `geth` also allows custom post numbers with `--port`